# How do I Enter a Polygon into a MySQL DB with EntityFramework 6?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, geospatial

I have the following C# POCO class:

```
public class TestGeoItem
{
    public int TestGeoItemId { get; set; }
    public DbGeometry PolyBounds{ get; set; }
}
```

The DbGeometry property gets correctly generated in the associated MySQL database as a "geometry" data type.

Now, if I add a single GPS point into this column, everything works correctly.  For example:

```
context.TestGeoItems.Add(new TestGeoItem(){
    PolyBounds = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(10 10)")
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, when I try to add a Polygon like I do below, it errors out:

```
context.TestGeoItems.Add(new TestGeoItem(){
    PolyBounds = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON((10 10,20 10,20 20,10 20,10 10))")
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here's the error:

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
>   MySql.Data.Entity.Metadata.NormalizeValue(TypeUsage type, Object value) +437
>      MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbConstantExpression expression) +307
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.DbConstantExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +73
>      MySql.Data.Entity.InsertGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree) +463
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +328
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +15
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +127
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +12
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree) +53
>
> [EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree) +128
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(Dictionary`2 identifierValues) +314
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +42
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +159
>
> [UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +329
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut) +11
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) +132
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update() +106
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&lt;SaveChangesToStore&gt;b__35() +13
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +157
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27() +25
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +9
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +221
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +11
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +113

In addition to using the DbGeometry.FromText method, I've also tried .PolygonFromText and that generates the same error.  I also can verify that the format of the polygon text is correct, that is:

```
POLYGON((10 10,20 10,20 20,10 20,10 10))
```

because if I try other formats, the class is smart enough to throw an invalid format exception.

Also, I want to note that I started with the DbGeography class (instead of DbGeometry) but soon discovered that the former doesn't work with MySQL as the data-type mappings aren't implemented.

Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution (or workaround) to this?  I'm seeing the exact same behavior...